# Write and style row by row to Excel using Python

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a JSON object that I want to write into Excel. I've managed to convert it to pandas dataframe and write it to Wxcel using to_excel function. I've managed to apply style to entire Excel once the data was inside. However I would need to do something like this:
foreach the object,
Write a row in excel,
style the row.

So basically write and style one row per time ( write, style, write, style .... )
What is the best approach or lib for this?

Update:

I created following object.

```
jsonTest= {
  "data": {
    "someId1": {
      "historical": {
        "idObj1": {
          "changes": [
            "x"
          ],
          "data": {
            "x": 100.9800,
            "y": 48.5970,
            "z": "22/01/2020"
          }
        }
      },
      "original": {
            "x": 105.9800,
            "y": 48.5970,
            "z": "22/01/2020"
      }
    },
    "someId2": {
      "historical": {
        "idObj1": {
          "changes": [
            "y",
            "x"
          ],
          "data": {
            "x": 100.1270,
            "y": 49.3150,
            "z": "22/01/2020",
          }
        },
        "idObj2": {
          "changes": [
          ],
          "data": {
            "x": 100.1270,
            "y": 49.3150,
            "z": "22/01/2020"
          }
        }
      },
      "original": {
           "x": 100.1270,
            "y": 49.3150,
            "z": "22/01/2020"
      }
    }
  },
  "header": {
    "name": "Title"
  },
  "status": "OK"
}
```

So the above is the object. Original is always one entry, and historical are all entries that differ from original.
The changes object in each historical tells me which columns are different from the original.

So I want an Excel that first takes the name from header and writes that in one row.

Then I take the first original entry colored with some color, and below that entry I write row by row each historical, bolding the columns that are different(the ones from changes). The process then repeats for each original.

I managed to append each row to one dataframe and convert it to excel using pandas. I tried styleframe, but all of those didn't seem to help me.

I would like to foreach this object, write first original(then style it) then go through each of that entries historicals( write one, style it, write second, style it) and so on

Comment: Hello, what have you tried? Can you please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question

Comment: What does "apply style" mean here? CSV is a text-only format; there is no portable way to add italics or color if that's what you mean. If you are writing native Excel files then show the actual code you have so far.